# Deduplicate Mysql request with arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

On my website, I have members. These members can create projets, and other members can follow every projects :

I have a first Mysql table named "members" with the following columns :
`id / name`

I have a second Mysql table named "Projects" with : 
`id / founder`

I have a second Mysql table named "Follow" with : 
`id / idmember / idproject`

**My goal is to show the crew of any member so :**

List all the members who :

- Follow the same(s) project(s) as me
- Follow a project that I have founded
- Have founded a projet that I follow

But I need to show the result with no duplicates. For example, if I follow your project, and i'm the founder of a project you follow, you need to see me only once.

I have started to work with arrays, and it seems the good solution, but i really can't figure how to do that.
Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to use MySQL's ``DISTINCT`` to eliminate duplicates. Please post your SQL code here so we can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `members.id` is `1337` and `Projects.founder` is foreign keyed to `members.id` then you can use `UNION` to make a table with duplicates and then `DISTINCT` on that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name
FROM (
  SELECT members.id, members.name
  FROM members, Follow f1, Follow f2
  WHERE members.id = f1.idmember
  AND f1.idproject = f2.idproject
  AND f2.idmember = 1337
  UNION
  SELECT members.id, members.name
  FROM members, Follow, Project
  WHERE members.id = Follow.idmember
  AND Project.id = Follow.idproject
  AND Project.founder = 1337
  UNION
  SELECT members.id, members.name
  FROM members, Follow, Project
  WHERE Follow.idmember = 1337
  AND Project.id = Follow.idproject
  AND Project.founder = members.id
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's very interesting, but maybe a bit to complex for me... I don't totally understand... :) f1 and f2 are aliases ?

Comment: Correct. Because we need that table twice in the `SELECT` statement we have to alias it.